# Only log10 transform the x-axis and not the values of my variables?

Tags: r, coordinate-systems

I want to change the coordinate system of my plot with

```
plot + coord_trans (x="log10")
```

But I only want to log transform the axis but not the values of the variable X that need to be plotted (as they include zero values).

I don't want equal spaces between the xticks.

Comment: I think the problem may come from using `coord_trans`. Have you tried if doing `scale_x_log10()` fixes the issue?

Comment: @aaumai Yes I have tried scale_x_log10(), but this produces  plot with equal spaces between the ticks (which I do not want). And I get  also warning message "transformation introuced infinite values in continuous x- axis"

Comment: Are you sure it's transforming the x values? If I run:
ggplot(starwars, aes(x=mass, y=height)) + geom_point()
and then:
ggplot(starwars, aes(x=mass, y=height)) + geom_point() + coord_trans (x = 'log')
it doesn't change the values at all, just the spacing

Comment: @krock thank you for thinking with me.  So , indeed coord_trans (x="log") does not change the values of the x-axis but only the spacing, which is just what I wanted, because I wanted the "zero" values to be plotted. But  the "zero" values are eliminated when I do this plot, so I assume the the X-values are logtransformed. So, maybe the question is, how can I plot the "zero" values on such a plot.

Comment: Oh I see, I would try adding a small value, like 0.001 to your values, or maybe just to the zeroes. That would let the zeroes show up and shouldn't affect the other values much. As long as your graph doesn't need to totally scientifically rigorous that should be fine.